# Vertical histograms

Tags: java

Could you please help me with below task?

Write a program which reads from the user three non-negative integers and then
prints, using symbols ’*’, a ‘histogram’ of the data represented by the numbers, i.e.,
three vertical bars, aligned at the bottom, with heights equal to the values of the three numbers.Do not use arrays, strings or any other kind of collections.

I tried something but I could only print the first histogram and I don't know how I can print out other columns next to it.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number 1: ");
    int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number 2: ");
    int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();


    System.out.print("Enter the number 3: ");
    int thirdNumber = sc.nextInt();


    for (int i = 0; i < firstNumber; i++) {

        System.out.print("*\n");

    }
```

Comment: Find the max of the 3 numbers. Your loop will go from max down to one. For each 3 numbers, print a star if i <= the number. Else print space.

Comment: Provide sample input and output

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Java so I'll give you the self-explanatory pseudocode which you can easily convert to any language:

```
int first, second, third;
ReadUserInput(first, second, third);
int max = MaxValue(first, second, third);
for (int i = max; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i <= a) {
        print("* ");
    } else {
        print("  ");
    }
    if (i <= b) {
        print("* ");
    } else {
        print("  ");
    }
    if (i <= c) {
        print("* ");
    } else {
        print("  ");
    }
    lineBreak();
}
```

***Edit:***

*elses added*

Columns will be printed in the exact same order user inputs the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printHistogram(int a, int b, int c) {
    int max = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);

    for(int i=max; i>=0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print((i<=a) ? "* " : "  ");
        System.out.print((i<=b) ? "* " : "  ");
        System.out.println((i<=c) ? "* " : "  ");
    }
}
```

This should help!